# В проекте LibGDX Android Studio не видит R.java и Activity

Tags: java, android, строки, libgdx, r.java-file

Создал проект в LibGDX, а при работе со строками обнаружилась вот такая проблема:

---

Android Studio не видит R.java а также не может(не видит) наследовать классы от Activity, Context и тд.  Пишет: cannot resolve ....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Добавлено: 
Нет, Ребилд проекта не помогает.
Так же как и синхронизация Сборщика

Добавлено2:
Нужно обратить внимание на то, что невозможно наследоваться он Других классов, я тут разобрался, их просто не существует, генератор проекта LibGDX просто их не создаёт.

Comment: *Build->Rebuild *? Не помогает?

Comment: Какое то время назад работало или это чья то библиотека и сразу так было?

Comment: Это libgdx,  сразу так есть., Всем спасибо, я разобрался,  там просто отсутствуют многие классы(context и тд.) а локализируется все иначе

Comment: Если вам не трудно, исправьте вопрос, указав, что проблема именно с `libgdx` и оформите ответ с вашим решением, отметив его верным. Это поможет другим участникам решить аналогичную проблему намного быстрее - в этом смысл данного ресурса. И не надо отмечать верным ответ, который не решил вашу проблему.

Comment: Ок, просто вопрос про ошибку R файла, а этот ответ решает проблему  с R файлом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Проверьте импорты, иногда там может появится строка по типу `import packege.android.java.R` или подобное с `R` на конце. Удалите эту строку.
2. У Вас не явные ошибки в программе (в коде `XML`) или в программе самой, которые не подчеркиваются, а из-за них `R.java` не пересоздается и текущий не работает.
3. У Вас явные ошибки в приложении, из-за которых багнутый `R.java` не может пересоздаться. Закомментируйте их и попробуйте `Build->Rebuild` или `project -> clean`.
   Я решал такую проблему путем сохранение `XML` файлов на раб. стол и удаления их из проектов. А сам проект комментил большими частями и пробовал `Build->Rebuild или project -> clean` до тех пор, пока не нашел часть кода, из-за которой багался `R.java`. Оказалось из-за совпадений в имени `ID` елементов

Comment: Нет, это не помогает, увы

Answer (score 0):

Периодически появляющиеся такие же проблемы я лечу следующим путём:
project -> clean
это заставит среду разработки обновить все ссылки и указатели, тем самым решив проблему